# Bug in jquery and IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

In IE8 the site guiavivotv.com.br has a bug in slider.

jQuery replace this:

```
<span data-value="-1"></span>
<span data-value="+1"></span>
```

To this:

```
<span data-value="-1"/>
<span data-value="+1"/>
```

And i do no why.
Is this a bug of jquery?

I tried use `replace()` and doesn't work either.

Comment: are you saying that your DOM inspector shows it this way? and what is the concern?

Comment: If you're creating the `span` with jQuery don't forget to close it `$('<span />')`. IE has problems otherwise.

Comment: my DOM inspector in IE8 only show <span data-value="-1"/><span data-value="+1"/>
My concern its clean this bug
This span is a normal HTML

Comment: @LuizHenriqueBezerra: *Why is that a problem?*

Comment: I do no @minitech and i do no why i can debug this.

Comment: @minitech it is a problem because miss the next butom